# Workflow Foundation 4 Instance Store for Oracle

Tags: oracle, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

We are strongly considering using Workflow Foundation 4 in our products, however must support both SQL Server and Oracle. Does anyone know an Oracle Instance Store provider for Workflow Foundation 4?
I know I could use SQL Server Express for it, but some of our customers use Oracle, and don't want to have an SQL Server, even free, to manage.
Tks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not mind using a commercial product then DevExpress has a very good solution. 16 database systems are supported along with re hosted designer and custom activities. Read more in this post [XAF Workflow persistence storage](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/eaf/archive/2011/08/24/xaf-workflow-persistence-storage.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

An updated devart link on the subject. It works well for me, for the persistance and the tracking participant also.

http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/?p=5566

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no publicly available version of the instance that works with Oracle. I have seen the question a number of times however so I can only encourage someone to publish one of those I suspect have been created privately on CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

Use this dll. We are using it and works well. Still need to check tracking and load testing.

http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21044&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=&sid=a5e672c431dafecb1e675b6fbecc5183